# MX Linux SSH folder in tmp directory

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

Even though I don't have SSH or OpenSSH installed on my machine, I noticed that I have the following directory `ssh-XXXXXX2ivnoU` in the tmp directory. Inside that directory is a file named `agent.2640`

What could be causing the creation of this directory and file? Is this a security issue?

Comment: I googled your question title, and the top hit is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979911/strange-folder-in-tmp-with-name-ssh Please make sure to do a little searching around before posting